# two records with same emailid but different detai as per decision split not receiving two emails

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, dataextensions, journeybuilder, data

in my data extension there are two records with same emailid but other details being different have different values for the column used in decision split as a filter so ideally two records should receive one email each from two decision split as each record satisfy one decision split path.
but only the 1st record is getting email, and not the second one.

is there any solution

Comment: Can you provide more detail as what is the subscriber key, primary key for the data extension and how you have rooted/populated the data extension in Contact builder.

Comment: primary key is row id which is connected to subscriber key. there is only one email field so i have used contact builder for that with row id connected to contact key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure that your duplicate Contacts are being injected into the Journey in the first place? My guess is that you have not changed the Contact Entry Mode for the Journey. Follow the Steps below

1. Create a new Draft of your Journey
2. Open the Journey in Journey Builder
3. Click on the cog (Settings) icon
4. Change the Entry Mode to 'Re-entry anytime'
5. Activate the new version and re-inject the Contacts into it (ensure that they have exited from previous versions first)

This will allow the Contact exist in a published Journey more than once.

Answer (score 0):

How are you sending it? If you're using User-Initiated sends make sure De-Duplicate by Email Address is set to no.